# Use different bean class in Jackson JSON based on variable?

Tags: java, json, subclass, jackson

I have JSON like the following:

```
[{
  'kind':'1',
  'value1': 'foo',
  'value2': 'bar',
  ...
},
{
  'kind':'2',
  'value1': 'foo',
  'value2': 'bar',
  ...
}
..]
```

Basically a list of objects with the same variables. In my code, I'd like to create an ArrayList of some class A, which would contain these objects. However, I'd like each object to be of subclass One or Two, depending on the 'kind' value.

How can I accomplish this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what Jackson calls "polymorphic type handling".  There's a good explanation of how to do this [here](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonPolymorphicDeserialization).  You need to tell Jackson to put the class name into the JSON when you serialize it, and use that class name when you deserialize it.  This is done via annotation:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use=JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, 
              include=JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property="kind")
```

[Source: @StaxMan (below).]

If you don't have control over the JSON format, you can use Jackson to deserialize it into some common intermediate object and then write code that creates the desired subclass object from it.  Alternatively, use the json.org library to deserialize the JSON string into an org.json.JSONObject, and then write code to construct your desired objects based on the JSONObject's properties.

Comment: Correct, this is the mechanism to use. In this case property name to use would "kind", so it'd be something like @JsonTypeInfor(use=JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include=JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property="kind"). Also; instead of class name, looks like a logical name ("1", "2") is to be used, hence 'JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME'.